# How to open Word document from commandline on certain page or similar

Tags: java, ms-word, document

I want from my java code to open word document. But not just to open the document but also to open on exact page or paragraph.

Any ideas or guidelines?

**NEWS!**
I found out that I can put bookmarks on specified places in the document ant then when I open the document I can go to them with Macro. Also Macro can be specified when you open document.
Like this:

```
String[] cmd  = {"cmd","/c","c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.exe","/mOpenPage","c:\\Navodilo.doc"};            
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Its ok only how to open the document with specified Macro **/mOpenPage** ***without*** to specify **path to winword.exe**, or you see some work-around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there is no way to do that.

Comment: Did I get you right in my answer that you want to process the Word-document in your application? Or do you just want to run an instance of MS Word with the desired document open?

Comment: I want to open the document on certain page in MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to open Word document on a specific page from command line, then you can use [Runtime.exec()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) to execute that.

Answer (score -1):

you can open word-document in your application by using Apache POI API you can open all office product by using POI.

Comment: As mentioned above: this is not, what Milan is looking for.